# SQL VS EF VS LDAP Connection string TYPE testing

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ldap, connection-string

I have 3 types of connection strings in my webconfig, we use them for various parts of the application such as LDAP login, DB status of a related but non integrated DB, and the EF DB First connection strings (EDMX)

I am looking to parse the connection string data in the most economical way system wise. currently

```
<add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://something.somewhere.something:389" />
<add name="DEV" connectionString="data source=SOURCE;initial catalog=Test;integrated security=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;User ID=tech;Password=*********;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="ConfigEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.Config.csdl|res://*/Data.Config.ssdl|res://*/Data.Config.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SOURCE;initial catalog=CATALOG;persist security info=True;user id=user;password=*********;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

In order to process the connection strings I find I need to try catch two sections in order to complete the process

First the try catch allows us to skip LDAP connection string safely (which should be skipped without the try catch

second it seems I need to cast the strings to retrieve the data from them...

```
try
{
    var ssb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder((((ConnectionStringSettings)c).ConnectionString));
}
```

vs

```
try{
        var ssb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder((new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(((ConnectionStringSettings)c).ConnectionString).ProviderConnectionString));
}
```

from there the code is identical

does anyone have thoughts on the best way to determin the *type* of connection string prior to running the code to prevent the need to rely on try catches.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `name` property of the connection string from `ConnectionStringSettings`. Use `name` property to identify the type of connection string.

You already have `ConnectionStringSettings` object, which is `c` (based on your code snippets).

Check for the `name` property as shown below to avoid `try` statement.

```
if(c.Name.Equals("ADConnectionString")) //ADConnectionString
{

}
else if(c.Name.Equals("DEV")) //DEV
{    

}
else //ConfigEntities
{

}
```